# Is there any Serena Dimensions CM on line user guide, wiki or doc's?

Tags: release-management, dimensions, serena

I'm looking for "ANY" Serena Dimensions CM user guide, maybe some wiki, anything. It seems that no one is using it nor have problems with it. I'll be much appreciate for your help

Comment: Curiously, how is your experience with Serena been?

Comment: After a few days, it was terrible in use, but after 3 months it's starting to do the job:) Oh and it's crashing on Vista;) all of the time.

Comment: It crashes on XP all the time too. I would officially like to nominate it for the worst SCM of ALL TIME award - there are no other contenders in its league. By the way I laughed when I read _no one is having problems with it_.

Comment: Good luck with that. The official manuals and online help are pretty much useless. They tell you how to do the obvious (click this to change this setting, click that to change that) but don't explain why or what you may want to do next. You get some basic definitions of the various objects but no details as to why you might want to use them or the best practices for setting them up. Some of the auxiliary guides are better (such as what streams are) but I have not yet seen any guides on how set up basic products from scratch. Click around and hope for the best before you go grey.

Comment: @HoundDog You know your SCM is special when you wish you were using CVS instead.

Comment: @badp is it really that bad? has it gotten any "less worse" in the later versions like 14?

Comment: @John since I wrote my comment the company changed versioning systems with IBM's roughly-as-bad solution and I changed jobs, so I cannot tell you. I routinely made changes that spanned about 30 different files across five Eclipse projects and my rollback strategy was making a screenshot of the commit window with the file revision numbers I was about to push…

Comment: I don't think version numbers can change a fundamentally broken design, though it could fix the builtin merge tool making a mess of utf-8 sources

Comment: Just curious as a contract gig I am involved with is considering switching from SVN (which I can deal with) to dimensions CM (which is essentially a big question mark)

Comment: Which version you're migrsting to which version of Dim Cm. I hope it's last one available. Because I assure you it will be a little  pain in the @$$ . Give me more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the Desktop client installed, you can find some help via the Help menu.

The Help mention also makes mention of available [courseware](http://courseware.serena.com/dimensions/index.html) which may also be of help.

Comment: I found the demonstrations in the _courseware_ link beneficial for end-users wanting a quick overview. However, wading through the application's Help menu requires persistence.

Answer (score 7):

I am using Serena Dimensions in 2018. It i now been taken over by micro focus and the documentation and knowledge base is made public. The link for all serena dimension related documentation can be found here:

http://help.serena.com/doc_center/doc_center.html#dcm

Entire Documentation portfolio is here:

http://help.serena.com/doc_center/cm/ver144/dmcm_all_docs_144.pdf

The way to reach to this to look for knowledge base links in the official serena website. Which will redirect to the current maintained database.

Answer (score 0):

We started using Serena Dimensions CM at work.  They should be able to provide you with a user guide.  I'm blindly staring at one now.

I would publish it somewhere but right on the front it states "Serena Proprietary and Confidential Information".  Do you have a Serena admin you might be able to ask?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Serena Dimensions serial number, you should be able to log into support@serena.com. In the My Download section, you will have access to the documentation.
Also, I think that the documentation (pdf files) is installed when you install the server.